# Custom org chart in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, active-directory, organization-browser, organization-profile

We have an on premise SharePoint 2013 farm. The out of the box org chart that comes with SharePoint is not good enough, so we are looking for some 3rd party org charts.

Any body here that has some experience with 3rd part org charts and can recommend any ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a custom Organizational chart for my client, which read user information directly from active directory. I am using google orgchart api in my custom code. If you wish to create i can help you otherwise if you can afford little sum of amount you can try PlumSail Org Chart that is also good to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try our [Plumsail Org Chart](https://plumsail.com/sharepoint-orgchart/). It has friendly navigation, quite flexible configuration, printing and it is HTML based. You can customize almost everything.

I'm part of the team who developed this product.